# How can I avoid transition during dynamic style in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using JavaScript to copy all styles of the `div#old` and use it to the `div#young` dynamically. I have successful done it, but when I add the `transition` property, the `div#young` applies a transition to all styles that I'm copying which I don't want.

Here is my code:

```js
let styles = getComputedStyle(old);
all_style = ['width', 'height', 'background', 'border-radius', 'transition']
for (var i = 0; i < all_style.length; i++) {
  young.style.setProperty(`--${all_style[i]}`, styles.getPropertyValue(all_style[i]));
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
}

#old {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
}

#young {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="old"></div>
  <div id="young"></div>
</div>
```

In summary I don't want the `transition` on `border-radius` of `div#young` and the reason why I'm adding `transition` is for my animation, so to remove it won't answer my question.

Comment: As first style on #young add "transition: none !important", see http://onezeronull.com/2016/10/06/disable-css-transitions-and-animations-temporarily-or-permanently/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make `0` the transition you don't want to happen. The order is important, the `all` need to be the first one:

```js
let styles = getComputedStyle(old);
all_style = ['width', 'height', 'background', 'border-radius', 'transition']
for (var i = 0; i < all_style.length; i++) {
  young.style.setProperty(`--${all_style[i]}`, styles.getPropertyValue(all_style[i]));
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
}

#old {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all,border-radius 0s;
}

#young {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="old"></div>
  <div id="young"></div>
</div>
```

If you don't want any you can update the display value after the styles copy.

```js
let styles = getComputedStyle(old);
all_style = ['width', 'height', 'background', 'border-radius', 'transition']
for (var i = 0; i < all_style.length; i++) {
  young.style.setProperty(`--${all_style[i]}`, styles.getPropertyValue(all_style[i]));
}
young.style.display="initial"
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
}

#old {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
}

#young {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background: var(--background,none);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
  
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="old"></div>
  <div id="young"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: why the `div#young` is fade in

Comment: @Gad because of the background transition, from transparent to red

Comment: @Gad added another idea in case you don't want any transition

Comment: exactly that's what I wanted Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add the transition with very little delay.

```js
let styles = getComputedStyle(old);
all_style = ['width', 'height', 'background', 'border-radius', 'transition']
for (var i = 0; i < all_style.length; i++) {
  if (all_style[i] !== 'transition') {
    young.style.setProperty(`--${all_style[i]}`, styles.getPropertyValue(all_style[i]));
  } else {
    setTimeout(() => {
      young.style.setProperty(`--${all_style[i]}`, styles.getPropertyValue(all_style[i]));
    }, 10); // 1 second / 100
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 60%;
}

#old {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  background: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 1s ease-in-out all;
}

#young {
  width: var(--width);
  height: var(--height);
  background: var(--background);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius);
  transition: var(--transition);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="old"></div>
  <div id="young"></div>
</div>
```